# How to add bullets in the body of email in Java

Tags: java, email

In my project, i'm using Servlet/JSP to send an email. I want to add bullets in the body of email when it sent.

Here is my code.

Servlet.java :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String subject= "[ MARMOTTE ][ "+env+" ] Demande d’habilitation";
    String body = "Demande d’habilitation du "+ chaineDate +" pour :\n";
    body += "identifiant : "+identifiant+" ;\n";
    body += "Nom : "+nom+" ;\n";
    body += "Prénom : "+prenom+" ;\n";
    body += "Téléphone : "+telephone+" ;\n";
    body += "Email : "+email+" ;\n";
    body += "UO : "+uo+" ;\n";
    body += "Etablissement : "+etablissement+" ;\n";
    body += "Motif de la demande : "+motif+".\n";

    String to = System.getProperty("mail.destinataire.moa");
    String from=email;  
    EMail.send(subject, body, to, from);
    response.sendRedirect("demanderHabilitationFait.jsp");
}
```

How to add bullets ?

Comment: bullets? can you be more concrete?

Comment: Make it a html email and then use html markup for the bullet points. Alternatively just use ascii characters (e.g. `-` or `*`) along with linebreaks. Any more details can only be given, if you provide more, e.g. what you tried, what `EMail.send(...)` is doing etc.

Comment: Does adding `\u2022` unicode to the string `body` help?

Comment: @PolRodríguez see the answer

Comment: @nullpointer yes !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the regex to use bullets in java.You can append it wherever you want

```
[\u2022,\u2023,\u25E6,\u2043,\u2219]\s\d\.\s[A-z]

for ex System.out.println("\u2022");
```

- will print normal bullet.

You can explore other expressions

Comment: Why have you got commas inside the regex?

Comment: each expression prints a different type of bullet.I have just written all the possible bullets that can be used.it is not any piece of code bur comma seperated general information

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I think it could be confusing, as it looks like a regex that defines what constitutes a bullet point. As such, you seem to be implying that the comma is also a bullet point (since it's inside the regex).